# How can I copy spreadsheet data at regular intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is continuously updated throughout the year.

At certain points in time throughout the year, say monthly, I would like to copy the data from some cells into other cells where they would not be updated any more, basically tracking how the values, or forecast, changed during the year.

I can, of course, always archive the file with different names, but it would be fantastic to have a smart solution for doing this.

Comment: Atm I have the same problem and I work around it by copiying the data (the numbers, not the formulas) to a different table. That works as a quick fix. Hopefully someone will know an automated way.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your items are listed down the left of the history table, and the dates are across the top. To the left of the table add a column referencing the cells holding the current value (including the current date at the top). 
Then when you want to add a new column, copy the left column, and "past as values" on the right.